# React Canvas, detect region in image at mouse click position

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image-processing, canvas

[image]

I have a canvas with this image

I want when I click into canvas I will the region at position that I clicked

Example when I click into red dot, I will get region 1-2-3-4-5-6

```
// input: mousePosition: {x, y}
// output: listPoint: [
//  {x1, y1},
//  {x2, y2},
//  ...
//  {x6, y6}
// ]
```

Does anyone have any ideas or any tools that could help me. Thank you

Comment: Render the canvas as an image and use an image map?

Comment: Can you create a native Javascript click event on the canvas that detects the click position? Do you know the coordinates of the region where your click should be handled?

Comment: I want some things like image processing to detect the region. as above example, my input is already a mouse position, and I want output is list point of region

Comment: How would you visually identify the region where the click should behave specially?

Comment: Is this image of a map or geospatial data? If it is you could use GIS and a JavaScript mapping library would handle the intersection of the mouse click and polygon layer, and then you could get the perimeter of the shape clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem impossible without list of points in image, I find another solution :(

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable through HTML [map areas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area). And I took the liberty to map out the coordinates from your image on a 500px x 450px area.

After creating the different areas you can make each area contain a `href` attribute which can either go to the area's page or execute JavaScript code by using a URL with the following format: `javascript:insert_your_code_here`.

If you want to get which area is on coordinates `x, y` you can simulate a click event on said coordinates.

Combining all of this, this is the code I've came up with:

```js
document.querySelector("#submitCoords").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const x = document.querySelector("#xInput").value;
  const y = document.querySelector("#yInput").value;

  document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click();
});

const clicked = (area) => {
  document.querySelector(
    "#clickResults"
  ).innerText = `Clicked ${area} area.`;
};
```

```html
<img src="https://i.imgur.com/myv6wss.jpeg" id="image" alt="Image" usemap="#workmap" width="500" height="450" />

<map name="workmap" id="workmap">
      <area
        shape="poly"
        coords="46,46,223,53,213,183,101,203,46,199"
        alt="A area"
        href="javascript:clicked('A')"
      />
      <area
        shape="poly"
        coords="409,57,446,57,446,348,390,262"
        alt="B area"
        href="javascript:clicked('B')"
      />
      <area
        shape="poly"
        coords="46,199,101,203,134,298,148,340,46,340"
        alt="C area"
        href="javascript:clicked('C')"
      />
      <area
        shape="poly"
        coords="148,340,134,298,390,262,446,348"
        alt="D area"
        href="javascript:clicked('D')"
      />
      <area
        shape="poly"
        coords="223,53,409,57,390,262,134,298,101,203,213,183"
        alt="Center area"
        href="javascript:clicked('Center')"
      />
    </map>

<br />
<input type="number" placeholder="Input x coordinate here" id="xInput" />
<input type="number" placeholder="Input y coordinate here" id="yInput" />
<br />
<br />
<button id="submitCoords">Submit coordinates</button>

<p id="clickResults"></p>
```

Codepen: [codepen.io/pen/wvdEYeZ](https://codepen.io/pen/wvdEYeZ)

Comment: Thank you, that not what I am looking for. by the way still give my bounty to first answer :)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of points and shapes you can then use the `click` event to find out where you are.

'Alternative approach' from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926559/when-is-a-point-in-the-plane-inside-a-simple-closed-path) answer on math.stackexchange.com

To find if we are in a shape we take a line segment from where the mouse click to outside of our canvas. We then count the number of times it intersects with the edges of our shape. If the number of intersections is odd then we are in the shape. We then do this for each shape until we find where the mouse is.

To calculate the if two lines intersect we can use the math from [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/) GeeksforGeeks article. It works by comparing the orientation of the points in the lines.

I have an example below.

```js
let globalPoints = [
    {"x":155,"y":395,"n":"A"}/*0*/,
    {"x":235,"y":630,"n":"B"}/*1*/,
    {"x":0,"y":630,"n":"C"}/*2*/,
    {"x":0,"y":380,"n":"D"}/*3*/,
    {"x":0,"y":80,"n":"E"}/*4*/,
    {"x":405,"y":80,"n":"F"}/*5*/,
    {"x":385,"y":355,"n":"G"}/*6*/,
    {"x":224,"y":598,"n":"H"}/*7*/,
    {"x":755,"y":520,"n":"I"}/*8*/,
    {"x":795,"y":80,"n":"J"}/*9*/,
    {"x":890,"y":85,"n":"K"}/*10*/,
    {"x":890,"y":630,"n":"L"}/*11*/,
    {"x":855,"y":630,"n":"M"}/*12*/,
    {"x":0,"y":0,"n":"N"}/*13*/,
    {"x":890,"y":0,"n":"O"}/*14*/
];

let shapePoints = [
    [0,1,2,3],
    [3,4,5,6,0],
    [0,7,8,9,5,6],
    [9,10,11,12,8],
    [9,10,11,12,8],
    [7,1,12,8],
    [4,13,14,10,9,5]
];

let lastClick = null;

class Shape {

    constructor(points)
    {
        this.points = points;
        this.filledIn = false;
    }

    draw(ctx) {

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
        ctx.lineWidth = 3;

        ctx.fillStyle = 'red';

        ctx.moveTo(globalPoints[this.points[0]].x,globalPoints[this.points[0]].y);

        for (let i =1;i < this.points.length;i++) {
            ctx.lineTo(globalPoints[this.points[i]].x,globalPoints[this.points[i]].y);
        }

        ctx.closePath();

        if (this.filledIn) {
            ctx.fill();
        }

        ctx.stroke();
    }

    toString()
    {
        let name = "";
        for (let i=0;i<this.points.length;i++) {
            name += globalPoints[this.points[i]].n;
        }


        return name;
    }

    //use the 'alternate method' from this answer
    //https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/926559/when-is-a-point-in-the-plane-inside-a-simple-closed-path
    calculateMouseClick(mouseX,mouseY)
    {
        //generate a ray that extends to outside of the shape,
        //we know -1,-1 will be outside as all points are positive
        let ray = {"p1":{"x":mouseX,"y":mouseY},"p2":{"x":-1,"y":-1}};

        let numIntersections = 0;

        //calculate all but last lines
        for (let i=0;i<this.points.length-1;i++) {
            let shapeEdge = {
                "p1":{
                    "x":globalPoints[this.points[i]].x,
                    "y":globalPoints[this.points[i]].y
                },
                "p2":{
                    "x":globalPoints[this.points[i+1]].x,
                    "y":globalPoints[this.points[i+1]].y
                }
            };

            if (doIntersect(ray.p1,ray.p2,shapeEdge.p1,shapeEdge.p2)) {
                numIntersections++;
            }
        }

        //last line wraps around to start of array
        let shapeEdge = {
            "p1":{
                "x":globalPoints[this.points[0]].x,
                "y":globalPoints[this.points[0]].y
            },
            "p2":{
                "x":globalPoints[this.points[this.points.length-1]].x,
                "y":globalPoints[this.points[this.points.length-1]].y
            }
        };

        if (doIntersect(ray.p1,ray.p2,shapeEdge.p1,shapeEdge.p2)) {
            numIntersections++;
        }

        if (numIntersections == 0 || numIntersections%2 == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

}

let shapes = [];

function init()
{
    "use strict";
    for (let i = 0;i< globalPoints.length;i++) {
        //add 50 to x and y so we don't draw at the very edge of the canvas
        globalPoints[i].x += 50;
        globalPoints[i].y += 80;
    }

    for (let i = 0;i < shapePoints.length;i++) {
        shapes.push(new Shape(shapePoints[i]));
    }

    draw();

    let canvas = document.getElementById("drawingArea");
    canvas.addEventListener("click",canvasClicked);
}

function draw()
{
    let canvas = document.getElementById("drawingArea");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    drawShapes(ctx);
    drawPoints(ctx);
    drawClick(ctx);
}

function drawShapes(ctx)
{
    "use strict";

    for (let i = 0;i<shapes.length;i++) {
        shapes[i].draw(ctx);
    }
}

function drawPoints(ctx)
{
    "use strict";

    ctx.font = "48px sans";
    for (let i = 0;i < globalPoints.length;i++) {
        ctx.fillStyle = "black";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(globalPoints[i].x,globalPoints[i].y,5,0,2*Math.PI);
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.fillStyle = "#444444";
        ctx.fillText(globalPoints[i].n,globalPoints[i].x-40,globalPoints[i].y-25);
    }
}

function drawClick(ctx)
{
    "use strict";
    if (lastClick == null) {
        return;
    }

    ctx.strokeStyle = "#33dd33";
    ctx.arc(lastClick.x,lastClick.y,10,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
}

function canvasClicked(event)
{
    "use strict";

    let mouseX = event.offsetX;
    let mouseY = event.offsetY;
    lastClick = {"x":mouseX,"y":mouseY};

    //clear out previous click
    for (let i=0;i<shapes.length;i++) {
        shapes[i].filledIn = false;
    }

    let foundShape = false;
    let shapeNameElem = document.getElementById("shapeName");
    for (let i=0;i<shapes.length;i++) {
        let isIn = shapes[i].calculateMouseClick(mouseX,mouseY);

        if (isIn) {
            shapes[i].filledIn = true;
            foundShape = true;
            shapeNameElem.innerHTML = "Clicked shape: "+shapes[i].toString();
            break;
        }
    }

    if (!foundShape) {
        shapeNameElem.innerHTML="";
    }


    draw();
}

/********************************
onSegment(), orientation(), doIntersect()
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/check-if-two-given-line-segments-intersect/

license CC BY-SA
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/copyright-information/
********************************/

// Given three colinear points p, q, r, the function checks if
// point q lies on line segment 'pr'
function onSegment(p, q, r)
{
    if (q.x <= Math.max(p.x, r.x) && q.x >= Math.min(p.x, r.x) &&
        q.y <= Math.max(p.y, r.y) && q.y >= Math.min(p.y, r.y))
    return true;

    return false;
}
 
// To find orientation of ordered triplet (p, q, r).
// The function returns following values
// 0 --> p, q and r are colinear
// 1 --> Clockwise
// 2 --> Counterclockwise
function orientation(p, q, r)
{
 
    // See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/orientation-3-ordered-points/
    // for details of below formula.
    let val = (q.y - p.y) * (r.x - q.x) -
            (q.x - p.x) * (r.y - q.y);

    if (val == 0) return 0; // colinear

    return (val > 0)? 1: 2; // clock or counterclock wise
}

// The main function that returns true if line segment 'p1q1'
// and 'p2q2' intersect.
function doIntersect(p1, q1, p2, q2)
{
 
    // Find the four orientations needed for general and
    // special cases
    let o1 = orientation(p1, q1, p2);
    let o2 = orientation(p1, q1, q2);
    let o3 = orientation(p2, q2, p1);
    let o4 = orientation(p2, q2, q1);

    // General case
    if (o1 != o2 && o3 != o4)
        return true;

    // Special Cases
    // p1, q1 and p2 are colinear and p2 lies on segment p1q1
    if (o1 == 0 && onSegment(p1, p2, q1)) return true;

    // p1, q1 and q2 are colinear and q2 lies on segment p1q1
    if (o2 == 0 && onSegment(p1, q2, q1)) return true;

    // p2, q2 and p1 are colinear and p1 lies on segment p2q2
    if (o3 == 0 && onSegment(p2, p1, q2)) return true;

    // p2, q2 and q1 are colinear and q1 lies on segment p2q2
    if (o4 == 0 && onSegment(p2, q1, q2)) return true;

    return false; // Doesn't fall in any of the above cases
} 



window.addEventListener("load",init);
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <script src="test.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="test.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
  <p id="shapeName"></p>
        <canvas id="drawingArea" width="1000" height="800"></canvas>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that not what I am looking for